# Can you create a temporary column in SQL Server to use as a variable in your code

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to extract some text in a column that contains comments. I wrote the code below which essentially looks for everything after the substring "ABILITIES:" and everything before a "."

The code works, but because of the contents of that column I had to convert every reference to it in varchar format, i.e. `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment)`

And as you can see, the code becomes very long and hard to read. My question is, is there a way to create a temporary column that basically just converts the `comment` column to varchar. And then I can just use that temp column as a variable in my code? Sort of like how you would with Python?

Or will you have to do that through a CTE?

```
SELECT *,
REPLACE(
    LEFT(
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment), CHARINDEX('ABILITIES:', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment))+12, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment)) - CHARINDEX('ABILITIES:', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment))+12),
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment), CHARINDEX('ABILITIES:', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment))+12, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment)) - CHARINDEX('ABILITIES:', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment))+12)) = 0
                THEN 0
            ELSE CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment), CHARINDEX('ABILITIES:', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment))+12, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment)) - CHARINDEX('ABILITIES:', CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),comment))+12)) - 1 
            END
    ), ',','') extracted_text
    
FROM table
```

Comment: You can put it in a TEMP table with some ID that corresponds to the main table, then anytime you need to reference the main table again you can join your temp table to it.

Comment: You can use a [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). But why do you have to convert the comment to VARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apply()` and a `values` constructor.

```
select <use column Mycol as much as you like>
from table t
cross apply(values(convert(varchar(max), comment)))x(Mycol);
```

Comment: I would suggest OUTER APPLY instead (and also I didn't understand how that is working for the OP. Probably she\he has very specific comments to make it possible).

Comment: How would outer apply make a difference the values table constructor will always return a row

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Comment: @CetinBasoz There is a difference between them in this case: `CROSS APPLY(VALUES` tends to get inlined into the outer query completely, whereas I find `OUTER APPLY(VALUES` tends to get turned into a `Constant Scan -> Left Join`. Each has pros and cons: very complex, slow expressions are better not inlined, but most are better inlined